# How to query Prometheus for a required metrics

Tags: go, kubernetes, prometheus

I have Prometheus up and running, and I am able to scrape the metrics and am able to query via browser at `localhost:9090` graphically, as per my requirement. But, I need to get certain metrics from my Go code and hence query from Go. So, how can I do this?
For example, say I need to get the result of the query:
`container_memory_usage_bytes{container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name="pod_name",container_label_io_kubernetes_docker_type="container"}` from Go.
How can I get the result?

Comment: Does this help?
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries

Comment: There is a client library for prometheus: https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang. `It has two separate parts, one for instrumenting application code, and one for creating clients that talk to the Prometheus HTTP API.`

Comment: any updates here?